# Why is ASP.NET replacing a Content-Length header with a Transfer-Encoding header when manually flushing a response?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Our web application (ASP.NET Web Forms) has a page that will display a recently generated PDF file to users. Because the PDF file is sometimes quite large, we've implemented a "streaming" approach to send it down to the client browser in chunks.

Despite sending the data down in chunks, we know the full size of the file prior to sending it, so we set the Content-Length header appropriately. This has been working in our production environment for awhile (and continues to work in our test environment with a virtually identical configuration) until today. The issue reported was that Chrome would attempt to open the PDF file but would hang with the "Loading" animation stuck.

Because everything was still working fine in our test environment I was able to use Firebug to take a look at the response headers that were coming back in both environments. In the test environment, I was seeing a proper 'Content-Length' header, while in production that had been replaced with a **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** header. Chrome doesn't like this, hence the hang-up.

I've read some articles and posts talking about how the Transfer-Encoding header can show up when no Content-Length header is provided, but we are specifying the Content-Length header and everything still appears to work while running the same code for the same PDF file on a test server.

Both test and production servers are running IIS 7.5 and both have Dynamic and Static Compression enabled.

Here is the code in question:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileToSendDown);
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=test.pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
var buffer = new byte[1024];
using (var fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    int read;
    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        if (!response.IsClientConnected) break;
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

I was fortunate to see the same behavior on my local workstation so using the debugger I have been able to see that the 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header is being set on the 2nd pass through the while loop during the call to 'Flush'. At that point, the response has both a Content-Length header and Transfer-Encoding header, but somehow by the time the response reaches the browser Firebug is only showing the Transfer-Encoding header.

**UPDATE**

I think I've tracked this down to using a combination of sending the data down in "chunks" AND attaching a 'Filter' to the HttpResponse object (we were using a filter to track the size of viewstate being sent down to each page). There's no sense in us using an HTTP filter when sending a PDF down to the browser, so clearing the filter here has resolved our issue. I decided to dig in a little deeper purely out of curiosity and have updated this question should anyone else ever stumble onto this problem in the future.

I've got a simple app up on AppHarbor that reproduces the issue: http://transferencodingtest.apphb.com/. If you check both the 'Use Filter?' and 'Send In Chunks?' boxes you should be able to see the 'transfer-encoding: chunked' header show up (using Chrome dev tools, Firebug, Fiddler, whatever). If either of the boxes are not checked, you'll get a proper content-length header. The underlying code is up on github so you can see what's going on behind the scenes:

https://github.com/appakz/TransferEncodingTest

Note that to repro locally you'd need to setup a local website in IIS 7.5 (7 may also work, I haven't tried). The ASP .NET development server that ships with Visual Studio DOES NOT repro the issue.

I've added some more details to a blog post here: ['Content-Length' Header Replaced With 'Transfer-Encoding: Chunked' in ASP .NET](http://gruffcode.com/2012/01/02/content-length-header-replaced-with-transfer-encoding-chunked-in-asp-net/)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but doing similar research I came across [this excellent post](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2012/01/02/lsquocontent-lengthrsquo-header-replaced-with-lsquotransfer-encoding-chunkedrsquo-in-asp-.net.aspx) explaining this very issue. It takes a specific set of circumstances to create this problem. Hope this helps a future reader.

Comment: That's the post I wrote up after asking the question, not getting an answer, and then finally figuring out some steps to consistently reproduce it. I updated the original question with the links to the sample app that reproduces it, but I suppose I should also add a link to the blog post as well.

Comment: You need to move the .Flush(); to outside the While statement and then that'll probably fix it.  Maybe a decade too late for you but anyone else it might help.

Answer (score 5):

From [an article on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc730855%28WS.10%29.aspx) it seems that you can disable chunked encoding:

```
appcmd set config /section:asp /enableChunkedEncoding:False
```

[image]

But it's mentioned under [ASP settings](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp), so it may not apply to a response generated from an ASP.NET handler.

Comment: I had already looked into these settings, but they had no impact on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Once `Response.Flush()` has been called, the response body in in the process of being sent to the client, so no additional headers can be added to the response.  I find it very unlikely that a second call to `Response.Flush()` is adding the `Transfer-Encoding` header at that time.

You say you have compression enabled.  That almost always requires a chunked response.  So it would make sense that if the server knows the `Content-Length` prior to compression, it might substitute that header for the `Transfer-Encoding` header and chunk the response.  However, even with compression enabled on the server, the client has to explicitally state support for compression in its `Accept-Encoding` request header or else the server cannot compress the response.  Did you check for that in your tests?

On a final note, since you are calling `Response.Flush()` manually, try setting `Response.Buffer = True` and `Response.BufferOutput = False`. Apparently they have conflicting effects on how `Response.Flush()` operates.  See the comment at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.buffer.aspx) and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput.aspx).

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make any sense that the headers are "changing" on the 2nd call to Flush, but I've tried this same code with and without sending the data in smaller chunks, and the browser only registers having received the 'Transfer-Encoding' header when multiple calls to flush are used. I'm working on a small sample app that will repro and will post that when I have it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was writing a large CSV (The file didn't exist I write a string line by line by iterating through an in memory collection and generating the line) by calling `Response.Write`  on the Response stream with BufferOutput set to false, but the solution was to change

`Reponse.ContentType = 'text/csv'` to `Reponse.ContentType = 'application/octet-stream'`

When the content type wasn't set to application/octet-stream a bunch of other response headers were added such as `Content-Encoding - gzip`