# IIS 8.5 forces incorrect Content-Length header

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We have a application that generates PDF files dynamically and forces a download of a the file. This code was working without issue on a Windows Server 2008. From what I can tell it appears that IIS is forcing the Content-Length to a value of 749 while it should be 83233. I have tried setting that value in the application code and IIS ignores it completely.

- Microsoft's URL Rewrite is installed but there are no entries for this site
- I have disabled compression of static and dynamic content
- Via the application code I am trying to set the Content-Length header and also setting the X-Content-Length header to the same value. This is how I am sure that the value is being overwritten by IIS
- When I hit the same URL via the built in web server of ColdFusion the download works without issue. This is why I know this is a issue with IIS or the connector between IIS and ColdFusion.

Here is the response headers from the server

```
Response Headers
-------------------------------------------------------------
Connection: close
Content-Length: 749
Content-Type    : application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 03:36:03 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=LasVegas.pdf
X-Content-Length    :83233
X-Powered-By    :ASP.NET
```

Here is the code

```
<cfcontent reset="true"/>
<cfset variables.temporaryFilePath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LasVegas.pdf">
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#getFileInfo(variables.temporaryFilePath).size#"/>
<cfheader name="X-Content-Length" value="#getFileInfo(variables.temporaryFilePath).size#"/>
<cfheader name="X-Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=LasVegas.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#variables.temporaryFilePath#" deleteFile="no">
```

Comment: Is this possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582637/why-is-asp-net-replacing-a-content-length-header-with-a-transfer-encoding-header

Comment: Jordan, I ended up ditching IIS and moved to Apache. It just wan't worth the trouble setting up

Comment: It appears we are getting a very similar issue - but we don't really have the option to move to Apache at this point I don't think!